# How to send pdf file to print dialog using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, printing

I have pdf files hosted on server and want that when user click a link to print pdf file then the print dialog should open and from there user can print that PDF file. It should work in Chrome, Firefox and Safari browsers.

Please let me know how this can be done in PHP/jQuery or in html/jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code once

```
$filepath = "path/to/file.pdf";
$filename = "file.pdf";
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));  // File size
header('Content-Encoding: none');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);  // Make the browser display the Save As dialog
readfile($filepath);  // This is necessary in order to get it to actually download the file, otherwise it will be 0Kb
```

**Note:** that this is just an extension to the HTTP protocol; some browsers might ignore it anyway.

Comment: This will download the pdf file onto the user PC. I need that print dialog should open when print link is clicked. So that user can print the PDF file.